# Exception handling with Retrofit2

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, retrofit, retrofit2

I am learning how to use `Retrofit2` but I am in trouble.

Is that any way to catch the `Response` object on `retrofit2.Retrofit` and throw an exception if the HTTP response code is out of the range 2xx?

I am implementing some JAX-RS rest services where my rest methods call another rest APIs to collect information and I would like to handle any HTTP error on the JAX-RS side:

```
public class HelloRest {

    @GET("/ping")
    public String ping() throws IOException {
        HelloService client = HelloServiceBuilder.getInstance();
        String response = client.sayHello().execute().body();
        LOGGER.info(response);
    }

    @GET ("echo/{msg}")
    public String echo(@PathParam("msg") String msg) throws IOException {
        HelloService client = HelloServiceBuilder.getInstance();
        String response = client.echo(msg).execute().body();
        LOGGER.info(response);
        return response;
    }
}
```

First, I have realized that the `execute()` method throws IOException so I had to add it to the rest methods signatures. That is okay, I can handle it properly with JAX-RS.

But what is the best way to handle errors which is related to HTTP responses where the response code is out of the range 2xx?

I do not want to write repeated code block to check the HTTP response code any time when I use Retrofit2 like this:

```
Response<String> response = client.ping().execute();
int responseCode = response.code();
if (responseCode < 200 && responseCode > 299) {
    throws AnyException("...");
}

String serverResponse = response.body();
...
```

Can I add something to the `Retrofit.Builder()` code block to handle this situation on a general way somehow?

```
public final class HelloServiceBuilder {

    private static final String SERVICE_URL = "...";

    private HelloServiceBuilder() {
        // do nothing
    }

    public static HelloService getInstance() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(SERVICE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .HOW-TO-CHECK-RESPONSES-HERE?
            .build();

        return retrofit.create(HelloService.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am going to create my rest client class with JAX-RS. It is part of Java, I do not need to add extra dependency to my pom, works like a charm and I need to create only one class instead of 2 or more:

```
public final class MyRestClient {
    private static Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    public static String hello() {
        String serviceUrl = "http://..../";
        String path ="hello";

        Response response = client
                .target(serviceUrl)
                .path(path)
                .request(ExtendedMediaType.APPLICATION_UTF8)
                .get();

        if (response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode()) {
            return response.getEntity(String.class);
        }

        throw new WebApplicationException(response);
    }
}
```